# QT Path for Omnet++ in ubuntu 22

Tags: omnet++, qt5.15

I am getting the following error in Omnet++ 6.0.1:

> /home/dice/Mohsan_Simulatiom_directory_C2JN_project/softwares_/omnetPP_distribution/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/microservicesapiplacement_6_22_2023/src/microservicesapiplacement_6_22_2023: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/dice/Mohsan_Simulatiom_directory_C2JN_project/softwares_/omnetPP_distribution/omnetpp-6.0.1/lib/liboppqtenv.so).

So my question is how to explicitly specify the Omnet++ to use the QT5.15 in path `/home/anaconda3/lib` instead of the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`, where it was not able to find it. Secondly, what is the method to explicitly install the QT5.15 in path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`?. Note that the application developed in Omnet++ did not have any programming mistakes so its build process (through Clang) was successful. The problem is during the execution, eclipse (IDE for Omnet++) continuously tries to find the QT5.15 version in the path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

To work around this error, I tried the command `qmake --version` which returned

> QMake version 3.1
> Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /home/anaconda3/lib

By this answer, I tried to export an activated path using
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
The command `ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` returned me

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 janv.  5  2022 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.12.8].

Another command `ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5C*` returned me the following:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1196 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.prl
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so -> libQt5Concurrent.so.5.12.8
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 -> libQt5Concurrent.so.5.12.8
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.12 -> libQt5Concurrent.so.5.12.8
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31400 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.12.8
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1240 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.prl
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -> libQt5Core.so.5.12.8
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.12.8
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.12 -> libQt5Core.so.5.12.8
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5519624 janv.  5  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.12.8

Answer (score 0):

Check the path to your `qmake` (for example using `which qmake`) and then open `configure.user` from main directory of your OMNeT++, uncomment and set that path in `QMAKE`.
Then recompile your OMNeT++ - i.e. `./configure`, `make`.